does the css path() function actually take <string> and does counter() actually return <string>
So all the documentation about this says I can use <string> as an input to path() but it seems thats either a lie or counter() does not actually return a <string>. Is there something I'm missing? I know css isn't parsed like a normal language so I'm assuming the counter isn't evaluated until after the path() function tries to parse it or something.


@counter-style path-data {
  system: fixed;
  symbols: "M0 0 L 140 140";
  suffix: " ";
}

svg {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: salmon;
  path {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 0.4rem;
    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      counter-reset: circled 1;
      d: path(counter(circled, path-data));
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      counter-reset: circled 1;
      --var: "M140 0 L 0 140";
      d: path(var(--var));
    }
  }
}
div::before {
  counter-reset: circled 1;
  content: counter(circled, path-data)
}
<svg>
  <path></path>
  <path></path>
 </svg>
<div>... just to double check im getting the right string</div>




According to the documentation you would normally use the counter() function in a content property, and "theoretically" it can be used wherever a <string> value is supported. The word "theoretically" strongly implies they know it doesn't. You might have found such a case.
